# How to animate a button with new view opening in IMDB iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone, button, imdb

I want to make an Demo App with animations like side top button in IMDB iOS App. I am not able to find the right library for me. I am new to animation in iOS. Can u please share an lib or share the code how to do it?

Description for a button: Button is opening with animated view when clicked someone give me a idea how to animate that view. The rest design i can make.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did not found any animation in the imdb's home page 'sleft top btn-_-

Comment: There is slight animation downwards when view is opening. which device r u using?

Comment: got it , it seems just make some view's basic animation together,1 : down view shrink & hide 2  btn click  3  in btn's action handler , make the down view animate (expand and show)

Comment: write a quick demo for u if u still got confuse , enjoy it :) https://github.com/ximmyxiao/testBarButtonAnimate

Comment: @ximmyxiao yes u have got it. Thanks for your efforts.